# Real Time Use of Abstract class

Tags: c#

I know about abstract class. But I have No idea for using in real time.. what is the use For Example.. save, Update, delete or sending Emails??? Any one can explain briefly with example like Employee Department Modules...

Comment: Abstract classes have nothing to do with any other technology other then basic .Net and OOP programming.  Examples and tutorials are off topic.

Answer (score 0):

ActionResult in MVC is abstract class, whereas ViewResult,JsonResult and etc are derived class.

As far as scenario to use abstract class is concerned, whenever you encounter a scenario where you conclude that a particular functionaity should be there but its implementation is not known you can use abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

I find it rather difficult to understand your question, but here is a real time examples on when to use an abstract class.

```
                    Employee (abstract class)
                          ^
                          |
                   ----------------
                   ^              ^
                   |              |
             HourlyEmployee      MonthlyEmployee
```

The Employee class is marked as abstract, where as both the HourlyEmployee and MonyhlyEmployee classes are inheriting from the Employee class.